# How to set an offset for cron jobs?

Tags: linux, cron

I have seven scripts to launch that take quite long to process, so for my first idea, I wrote my crontab like this:

```
0 */3 0 0 0 /home/personal/my-script-1
0 */3 0 0 0 /home/personal/my-script-2
0 */3 0 0 0 /home/personal/my-script-3
0 */3 0 0 0 /home/personal/my-script-4
...
```

In this case all my scripts are launching together. What I want, is to start with an offset. So I changed my `crontab` like this and put an 5 min offset between jobs:

```
0 0-59/3 0 0 0 /home/personal/my-script-1
0 5-59/3 0 0 0 /home/personal/my-script-2
0 10-59/3 0 0 0 /home/personal/my-script-3
0 15-59/3 0 0 0 /home/personal/my-script-4
...
```

But I'm not sure of my edits. Will my scripts be scheduled to launch with a space of three hours and offsetted by 5 minutes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid not.

The second field of the crontab specifies the hours of the day which the script will run. So the first one will run every three hours from 0h00 to 59h00 (which is invalid! hours only go from 0-23), the next one every three hours from 5h00 to 59h00, and so forth.

If you want to set the minute, you need to use the *first* field.

```
0 */3 0 0 0 /home/personal/my-script-1
5 */3 0 0 0 /home/personal/my-script-2
10 */3 0 0 0 /home/personal/my-script-3
15 */3 0 0 0 /home/personal/my-script-4
```

This will run the second script at 0h05, 3h05, etc., the third script at 0h10, 3h10, etc.

---

Better still, if the scripts should always be run in the same sequence, just write another script that calls them all in sequence. This way, you will not have problems if one of the scripts happens to take six minutes or more.

Comment: Could also separate them with `&&`s directly in the crontab rather than another separate script.